# Sending http requests with params using Angular/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, json

I have a front-end app in Angular and back-end in Rails. I totally decoupled those two for sake of easy maintenance.

In my backend in Rails, I have a model called Document with three different params (User_id(integer), Data(json), Title(string)). In my front end, I have a variable called `formData` which is json data living in `localStorage` in Angular. I'm not sure whether I'm writing the code correctly to send `formData` as a parameter in HTTP request below.

Here is the request I have:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/documents', { user: $scope.user, formData: $scope.formData }, function (response) {
                $scope.isSaved = true;
                console.log(response);
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log("It has been successfully saved!")
                }
            });
```

The origin I'm sending the request is `http://localhost:3001/i129`. From this website, I need to extract the document title where user is at (which is i129) and User_ID. How do I do that?

Am I send `formData` correctly above? Let's say

Answer (score 0):

For CRUD operations just like you want I'd recommend to use a higher level tool in the **Angular** frontend like the `$resource` service which is built on top of `$http`. On [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) you have an explanation of how to use it and an entire example with movies that you can probably relate to your needs.

Basically, you configure the endpoint of your backend API and then you can use nice methods like `get()`, `save()` and `delete()` instead of **http** API calls.

Hope it helps!